# Visual Studio 2017 debugger keeps looking for DLL's .obj file after project folder structure changed

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

My setup

- Win10
- Visual Studio 2017 ver 15.9.15

While trying to step into a DLL API, VS throws the error at me:

```
Error: Unable to open file /path/to/old/folder/intermediate/file.obj. Error code = 0x80070003
```

This is different from questions such as

- [VS2017 blocking on non-existing object files when debugging with pdb file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50489343/987846)

in that the error message clearly shows that the file was from an outdated location after I restructured the project.

I've tried

- `Clean Solution` and rebuild
- Tweak the debug config to use `/DEBUG:FULL` for all the DLL's and EXE's.

to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself.
All my DLL projects used to output to a location different from my main exe's folder. After I redirect those paths to the exe's folder and rebuild. The problem is gone. It's interesting that the app runs without DLL issues either way.