# Why does this C++ Class code break the compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm working on a project for my university, here is a class I have made using C++. Having this class completely breaks Visual Studio compiler. Not including this class will run the program perfectly fine. This is my first time using c++ classes, I'm very familiar with Java OOP programming but this doesn't make sense to me.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::vector;

namespace Studentas {

    class Studentas {
    private:
        string vardas_, pavarde_;
        float mediana_, vidurkis_, egzaminas_;
        vector<int> pazymiai_;

    public:
        inline string vardas() const { return vardas_; }
        inline string pavarde() {
            return pavarde_;
        }
        inline float mediana() {
            return mediana_;
        }
        inline float vidurkis() {
            return vidurkis_;
        }
        inline float egzaminas() {
            return egzaminas_;
        }
        inline vector<int> pazymiai() {
            return pazymiai_;
        }

        inline void pakeistiVarda(string _vardas) {
            this->vardas_ = _vardas;
        }

        inline void pakeistiPavarde(string _pvd) {
            this->pavarde_ = _pvd;
        }
        inline void pakeistiEgzamina(float _egz) {
            this->egzaminas_ = _egz;
        }
        inline void pakeistiMediana(float _med) {
            this->mediana_ = _med;
        }
        inline void pakeistiVidurki(float _vid) {
            this->vidurkis_ = _vid;
        }

        float skaiciuotiMediana();
    };

}
```

These are the errors I get, I don't believe any of them are relevant as there's 13 errors coming from the compiler.
[image: Error display]

There are instantly a ton of errors, almost like the compiler doesn't like something. But nothing is marked incorrect visually.

Comment: Please post your code/errors as text, not images.  For people that can't see images for one reason or another your question is unanswerable.

Comment: The code you posted is fine (if a bit clunky, those `inline` are implicit, and those prefix underscores give me the eeby-jeebies). The issue is probably with your project and/or system.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the images. I'll try to reinstall c++ compiler, since I have no clue what the problem is. This is the only class which causes such issues, few other classes are not causing any problems compiling. NVM: I actually tried with Replit.com and it gives errors there as well, cause the errors are unreadable I can't figure it out.

Comment: @JonathanGrand Before you go and reinstall software, the bug could also be coming from a file that `include`s this code. A lot of errors in ok code residing in a header is often the sign of a missing closing brace somewhere else.

Comment: There’s no compilation error in your code, it compiles just fine.

Comment: Try creating a new project and add exactly the code you have posted to see if it still has these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your code, it works fine for me. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489343/vs2017-blocking-on-non-existing-object-files-when-debugging-with-pdb-file) out. Try going to  Properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Debug Info Generate Debug Information optimized for sharing and publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you build your project before debugging?

If so, you could go to Project properties->Linker -> Debugging, then set the Generate Debug Info to `Generate Debug Information (/DEBUG)` or `Generate Debug Information optimized for sharing and publishing (/DEBUG:FULL)`.

[image]

For more details I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[/DEBUG (Generate Debug Info)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?view=msvc-160)

> When you specify /DEBUG with no additional options, the linker defaults to /DEBUG:FULL for command line and makefile builds, for release builds in the Visual Studio IDE, and for both debug and release builds in Visual Studio 2015 and earlier versions. Beginning in Visual Studio 2017, the build system in the IDE defaults to /DEBUG:FASTLINK when you specify the /DEBUG option for debug builds. Other defaults are unchanged to maintain backward compatibility.

If you are using vs2107 and above, I suggest you should use `/ DEBUG: FULL`.

Comment: @Jonathan Grand Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.
Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.